# ¿Como pasar saltos de línea en PHP $_REQUEST de Textarea?

Tags: php, javascript, textarea

De un textarea paso el texto:

```html
<textarea id="respuesta1b" class="campostexto2" type="text" cols="40" rows="5" style="font-size: 16px;" maxlength="500" onKeyDown="cuenta();" onKeyUp="cuenta();"  name="textarea2" required></textarea>
```

```js
var respuesta2 = document.getElementById("respuesta1b").value;
alert(respuesta2);
//Recibe el texto correctamente con saltos de linea, acentos, etc.

revisa.open('POST', 'inserta.php?respuesta1='+respuesta1+'&respuesta2='+respuesta2, true);
// lo envía "correctamente"
//En Php lo recibo de esta forma
$contesta = $_REQUEST["respuesta2"];
//Y aquí me muestra el texto sin saltos de linea Ejemplo:
/*Hola, 
aquí un salto

aquí otro */

// y la salida es: Hola,aquí un saltoaquí otro.
```

¿Como puedo solucionarlo? no me gustaría cambiar la estructura en la que paso los datos, pero ¿hay solución?

Comment: Los saltos de línea sí se pasan, pero el navegador los interpreta como espacios, a menos que en PHP uses `echo nl2br($contesta);` para agregar la etiqueta `<br>` en cada salto.

Comment: Hola hay una solución muy simple, que te permite mandar los datos "como están" y recuperarlos tal cual fueron enviados `'respuesta1=' + encodeURIComponent(respuesta1) + '&respuesta2=' + encodeURIComponent(respuesta2)` Cuando los leas de $_POST no necesitas hacer decode y cuando los recuperes para enviarlos basta pasarlos al value del área.

Comment: @quevedo ¡Mil gracias por tu respuesta! Los solucioné con JSON.stringify(datos) del comentario de Pollo asi: var convierte1 = JSON.stringify(respuesta1); var convierte2 = JSON.stringify(respuesta2); y lo puse dentre del revisa.send("respuesta1="+respuesta1+"&respuesta2="+respuesta2); y sigue la linea que necesitaba: revisa.open('POST', inserta.php, true); Pero se que mas adelante me puede funcionar mucho tu respuesta. saludos

Answer (score 0):

El primer problema es que no estás codificando el texto para poder enviarlo, que se haría con [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/encodeURIComponent).

Pero el problema mayor es que estás mezclando los métodos. En vez de enviarlo como parte del contenido del POST, lo estás enviando como si fuera un GET.

Para enviar un POST desde JavaScript que no sea desde un form:

```
let url = 'https://tuweb.com/script.php', //<--------- modificar
    datos = {
        respuesta1: respuesta1,
        respuesta2: respuesta2
    };

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST', 
  body: JSON.stringify(datos)
}).then(res => {
  console.log('Enviado. Respuesta:', res);
});
```

Comment: El problema, si lo hago de esta forma, es que ya no puedo recibir ahi mismo otros datos. revisa.open('POST', 'inserta.php?respuesta1='+respuesta1+'&respuesta2='+respuesta2, true); ¿En esta linea puedo hacer algo? ¿o previo pero que no modifique esta linea? ya que debo cargar ahi un resultado. ¿Se puede?

Comment: @Abner mira cómo se está configurando la variable `datos` en mi respuesta. Ahí se puede agregar lo que quieras.

Comment: Lo pude resolver con tu ayuda y aportación de JSON.stringify(datos)

Comment: asi: var convierte1 = JSON.stringify(respuesta1); var convierte2 = JSON.stringify(respuesta2); y lo puse dentre del revisa.send("respuesta1="+respuesta1+"&respuesta2="+respuesta2); y sigue la linea que necesitaba: revisa.open('POST', inserta.php, true);

Comment: y le quite las comillas en PHP con $recibe1 = preg_replace('/[\n|""]+/', PHP_EOL, $recibe1); MIl gracias por tu respuesta @Pollo.